# Gravar XML a partir de um List

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Estou desenvolvendo um C# Console Application que carrega uma Lista e depois grava um arquivo XML com o conteúdo desta Lista.

**Classe**

```
public class Equipamento

    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Marca { get; set; }
        public int Ano { get; set; }

    }
```

**Estou gravando o XML assim:**

```
private void GravaListXMLinq(List<Equipamento> ListaEquipamentos)
{
    string caminho = @"D:\XML\saida.xml";
    try
    {
        var xEle = new XElement("Equipamentos",
                    from emp in ListaEquipamentos
                    select new XElement("Equipamento",
                                    new XAttribute("ID", emp.Id),
                                    new XElement("Marca", emp.Marca),
                                    new XElement("Ano", emp.Ano)
                               ));
        xEle.Save(caminho);
        this.Log().Info("Arquivo XLM gravado em: " + caminho);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.Log().Error("Ao gravar XML em: " + caminho + " Erro: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Funciona, mas queria gerar o XML de forma mais dinâmica, sem a necessidade de explicitar os campos, somente com o conteúdo da lista.

Se existir outra forma mais simples aceito sugestões de como proceder.

Comment: O que você quer dizer com `sem a necessidade de explicitar os campos`?

Comment: No `select` tenho de colocar os nomes dos campos `new XAttribute("ID", emp.Id` e não queria ter este trabalho.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode serializar sua lista diretamente no `XML`, dessa forma;

```
private void GravaListXMLinq(List<Equipamento> ListaEquipamentos)
{
    string caminho = @"D:\XML\saida.xml";
    try
    {
            //cria o serializador da lista
            XmlSerializer serialiser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Equipamento>));

            //Cria o textWriter com o arquivo
            TextWriter filestream = new StreamWriter(caminho);

            //Gravação dos arquivos
            serialiser.Serialize(filestream, ListaEquipamentos);

            //Fecha o arquivo
            filestream.Close();

            this.Log().Info("Arquivo XLM gravado em: " + caminho);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.Log().Error("Ao gravar XML em: " + caminho + " Erro: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

A forma mais simples que encontrei foi essa (apesar de gostar de definir os nomes dos campos, como está em sua pergunta).

Se quiser mais exemplos, [esta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8334527/4843158) possui mais algumas respostas.

Comment: Ih camarada quando tempo!? Valeu funcionou como esperado. Muito obrigado.

Comment: @Jota Tem um tempinho mesmo. Que bom que funcionou, qualquer coisa é só avisar.

Answer (score 1):

Segue em anexo a solução para o seu problema, é válido ressaltar que para não retornar uma exceção a pasta onde o XML será gravado deve realmente existir.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Equipamento
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Marca { get; set; }
        public int Ano { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var lista = new List<Equipamento> {
                new Equipamento { Ano = 1990, Id = 1, Marca = "1"},
                new Equipamento { Ano = 1990, Id = 2, Marca = "2"},
            };
            GravaListXMLinq(lista);
        }

        private static void GravaListXMLinq(List<Equipamento> listaEquipamentos)
        {
            const string caminho = @"C:\XML\saida.xml";
            try
            {
                XmlSerializer xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Equipamento>));
                var subReq = listaEquipamentos;
                using (var sww = new StringWriter())
                {
                    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww))
                    {
                        xsSubmit.Serialize(writer, subReq);
                        var xml = sww.ToString();
                        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
                        XElement root = doc.Root;
                        root.Save(caminho);
                        //this.Log().Info("Arquivo XLM gravado em: " + caminho);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //this.Log().Error("Ao gravar XML em: " + caminho + " Erro: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Essa parte `XmlSerializer(typeof (MyObject));` esta com erro. Alterei para `typeof(Equipamento)`, mas gera um XML sem nada. O que devo usar? Mas agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Comentar, atualizei o código escrevi coletando varias referências e como estava no celular não escrevi devidamente

Comment: Contudo segue um código testado e funcional, perdão.

Comment: Valeu a ajuda. Agora esta funcionando.